# Strange Analysis Polynomial Question (Lagrange Interpolation?)

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-interpolation

We have $0\leq x_0\lt x_1\lt\,...\,\lt x_N\leq1$, where all $N+1$ distinct points are in $[0,1]$ and I must show:
If $p$ is a polynomial with degree $\leq N$, and $$Q_k(t)=\prod_{\substack{0\leq i\leq N}\\
\:\:\:i\neq k}\frac{t-x_i}{x_k-x_i}$$
then $$p=\sum_{k=0}^Np(x_k)Q_k.$$
I have honestly no idea where to start. I've done some research and can see this relates to Lagrange polynomials, however, that is well beyond the scope of the course I am on - I believe I'm meant to use basic analysis methods / ingenuity to prove this,

Comment: Did you mean to write $Q_k(t) = \prod_{\substack{0 \leq i \leq N \\ i \neq k}} \frac{t-x_i}{x_k - x_i}$? Your current expression looks for $p$ looks line a line to me!

Comment: Yes thank you! edited now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This relies on two observations.

$1.)$ The function defined by  $f = \sum_{k=0}^Np(x_k)Q_k$ satisfies that $f(x_i) = p(x_i)$ for $0 \leq i \leq N$. (This is because $Q_k(x_i) = \delta_{ik}$

$2.)$ If two polynomials of degree $N$ agree on $N+1$ points are the same.

From this you can conclude $$ \sum_{k=0}^Np(x_k)Q_k = p$$

To prove $2$, suppose $f,g$ were two polynomials of degree $N$ for which $f(x_i)= g(x_i)$. Then $f-g$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq N$ with $N+1$ roots: $x_0, \dots x_N$.

Not possible unless $f-g = 0$ or $f=g$.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about proving 2?

Comment: I've edited with a proof. It's both a fundamental and very useful result.

Comment: That was really useful thanks